# VS2013 Web Configuration Tool missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So apparently Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom decided this should only be available through command line since they removed Cassini.

I'm getting `Invalid physical path` when running the command. I referenced the screenshot and my current directory and path look identical.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Accessing the ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Note: This is the application that is used to configure membership.

Comment: *Note: This is the application that is used to configure membership.* Configuring membership in this way is deprecated and you need to use Cloud 2.0 Membership. There is no configuration, just sign in with your favourite social media account!

Comment: Don't want to use cloud anything. Want to use what's worked absolutely fine in the past. I ended up installing VS2012 and opened the project in there.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered that question in another thread. Have a look at this answer.

[Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool/20555928#20555928)

P.S. I would write that as a comment if I had enough reputation, that's why I am sending that as an answer. Sorry about that in advance :)