# Web Configuration option in Visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have installed visual studio 2013 and I'm trying to configure asp.net web to allow or deny permissions to certain set of pages in website that I have created through visual studio, but I can't see any option to configure as in previous versions of Visual studios. I have researched and tried some steps provided in this [LINK in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool) without any luck.

I can revert back to Visual studio 2010/2012, but why is it that I have to revert back ? There could be a reason why Microsoft has removed this option to configure or for any other commercial reasons ?

Anyway, my main priority here is how to get a fix for the issue I am facing or is there any alternative ways to achieve it? I heard that configuring membership now involves cloud 2.0 Membership - source -> [COMMENT FROM OTHER USER IN STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782794/vs2013-web-configuration-tool-missing)

I have registered IISEXPRESS with this command:

> "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
>   /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles
>   /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm

and when I try to open the url: `http://localhost:8089/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=[C:\Users\kiriti\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebSite1]\&applicationUrl=/`

I get an error saying:

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'PhysicalDirectory' is invalid. Parameter name: PhysicalDirectory at System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping..ctor(VirtualPath virtualDirectory, String physicalDirectory, Boolean isAppRoot, String configFileBaseName) at System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping..ctor(String physicalDirectory, Boolean isAppRoot) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.OpenWebConfiguration(String path, String appPhysPath, Boolean getWebConfigForSubDir) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.VerifyAppValid()

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

remove '[' and  ']' from your application physical path

Answer (score 0):

Try to Copy your project to somewhere else like `C:\MyProject\`

According to this [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1085627.aspx) it could be either the directory of the project too deep or it had illegal Character(s)

I had this problem before and this solution solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error and I found the solution to the problem.

Make sure that your application path uses the backslash and not the forward slash. 
e.g. http://localhost:8080/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=**c:\MyProject\MySite**&applicationUrl=/

Answer (score 0):

The reason this usually happens is because, the name of the folder under projects is Website1 and the same time if you check the directory, there should be a file named Website1.sln (*sln extension). Basically .sln file is clashing with your project folder name. Solution: Change the name of .sln file to something else.

Secondly, remove [] brackets. You don't need them.

I hope this helps.

Thanks.